# How to display the image in a cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, cell

I am new to iphone development.I want to display  image in each cell.I am having only the url of the image in a array.please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: Each cell?  What cells?  What have you tried?

Comment: In a table view cell? Please clarify your question and add code to indicate what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//put this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath.... I'm assuming you have an array of url's that point to images
id urlPath = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexOfImage];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}   

//insert an image into your cell
cell.imageView = image;
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but it's a decent way to get started customizing your tableview cells.  ImageView is one of many properties of the UITableViewCell class.

Further reading.... [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This is workable, but it's best not to load images from the network on the main thread (if from disk it's generally okay)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at this apple's sample code, it is great and shows how to implement what you need plus other useful stuff:
[Advanced Table View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/)

Comment: i am having the url of the image in a string array, the above example has all images in the resource.